# How to write prepared statements for this query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, prepared-statement

Hi i have written a join query for my app and its working. My next requirement is to convert that query to prepared statement where I am stuck.

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TableA.TABLE + " as d LEFT JOIN " + TableB.TABLE + " as c ON d."+ TableA.DAMAGECODE + "=c." + TableB.DAMAGECODE + " AND d."
+ TableA.INDEX + "=c." + TableB.DAMAGECODEINDEX + " AND d."
+ TableA.OBJECTTYPE + "=c." + TableB.OBJECTCLASS + " WHERE d."+ TableA.LEAF + " = '1' AND d." + TableA.OBJECTTYPE + " = ? AND " + "(d."+ TableA.DAMAGECODE + " LIKE ? OR d." + TableA.DAMAGETEXT + " LIKE ?) AND c." + TableB.CONSTRUCTIONSERIES + " = ? ORDER BY " + TableA.DAMAGETEXT;

cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(objectClass),"'%" + query + "%'","'%" + query + "%'",constructionSeries});
```

When i ran raw query i am getting results ,but when ran the above prepared statements i am getting cursor count always zero

Comment: Can you, for the sake of my mind, propose a simplified `String` without those concatenation ? Something like `Select * from FOOBAR where id = ?` It is unclear what you are not able to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the `'` yourself when you pass a `String` parameters, the `PreparedStatement` will manage those itself.

```
"'%" + query + "%'"
```

For the moment you have condition like

```
where columnA = "'%somethingToFind%'"
```

So unless you have a value in `columnA` like `'somethingToFindInColumnA'` (note the quote at the begin and the end of that `String`). You will never get a result.

Remove those to get something like :

```
"%" + query + "%"
```

Full answer :

```
db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(objectClass),"'%" + query + "%'","'%" + query + "%'",constructionSeries});
```

Become :

```
db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{String.valueOf(objectClass),"%" + query + "%","%" + query + "%",constructionSeries});
```

Comment: yeah worked like a charm .Thank you very much .You saved my time .cheers